# Android Dialog Popup

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an android pop up dialog for login or something. The client receives the pop up so as to wait until he is logged in. How can I prevent the dialog from canceling when the user clicks out of the dialog window?

Comment: Show more code in detail...

Comment: yes, it is possible. Just add  `.setCancelable(false)`

Comment: Use `dialog.setCancelable(false);` to prevent from cancelling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#setCancelable(boolean)

**setCancelable**

```
public void setCancelable (boolean flag)
```

Sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the BACK key.

**setCanceledOnTouchOutside**

```
public void setCanceledOnTouchOutside (boolean cancel)
```

Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not already set.

Answer (score 1):

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait... ");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();
```